# How to change what ssh:// uses?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, ssh

There seems to be two different SSH client versions on my Macbook Pro running Sierra (10.12.4). If I do the following:

`$> ssh dev`

It works just fine. However, if I do the following:

`$> open ssh://dev`

It opens a new terminal which then complains about the encryption settings in my `ssh_config` file. Researching the specific complaints, I found out that opening through the protocol handler is using an older version of SSH.

How do I change which SSH client the protocol redirects to?

Comment: What do you get when you type "which ssh" and what do you get when you type "ps aux | grep ssh" after running the second command?

Comment: Which ssh: `/usr/local/bin/ssh`

The SSH process kills itself after running it through the second method, I'm not sure how I would keep it alive to see it in the process list.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a tool that is very comfortable to change the default app for specific URL handlers.

### Change the ssh URL scheme with RCDefaultApp

1. Download [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) Version [2.1](http://www.rubicode.com/Downloads/RCDefaultApp-2.1.X.dmg)
2. Install the Preference Pane
3. Go to System Preferences > Defaults Apps > URLs
4. Go to "ssh"
5. On the right side, select your preferred application

It will look very similar to this screenshot:

[image: RCDefaultApp Screenshot showing the preference pane]

Comment: The problem isn't based on the terminal application, but rather which SSH binary is being called. I can change the application to open iTerm instead of Terminal and the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about changing the ssh:// protocol client,

Per https://superuser.com/a/548122/202319 , you can modify `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist` to open any app with a registered identifier when ssh:// or another URL is encountered.

This is not a perfect solution, because it still requires an app bundle, or will use Terminal.app (which is what you see already).

But, you should be able to fix your .login or .bashrc files so the default Terminal.app shell would use your preferred `ssh` anyway.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `.login` and `.bashrc` config changes? The problem is not which terminal app is being opened, but rather which SSH binary is being executed. Calling `ssh` inside a terminal session calls one binary, but have the terminal opening the connection through the protocol is calling another SSH binary.

Answer (score 0):

I have no mac to check right now but my guess is:

Mac comes with ssh client /usr/bin/ssh

You installed newer version on /usr/local/bin/ssh

You can try removing /usr/bin/ssh or rearrange order of $Path so it'll pick /usr/local/bin/ssh first

Comment: Unfortunately Apple killed the ability to touch stuff in /usr/bin. I had already tried re-arranging the PATH variable to put my local bin upfront, but it seems that the ssh:// protocol is explicitly calling /usr/bin/ssh as the change didn't work.

Comment: you can if you disable SIP
in recovery mode:
`csrutil disable`